# Que el mensaje de redirección este centrado

Tags: laravel-5

Veran, tengo en una función el siguiente metodo:

```
return back()->with('message',['success','Su curso de idiomas se ha introducido con exito. ¿Tienes algun otro curso de idiomas que quieras añadir?']);
```

Esto acaba dando el siguiente resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y ahora mi pregunta: ¿Hay algún modo de dar estilo a ese mensaje, para que se ponga en negrita o se centre el texto? La pantalla de mi PC es grande, por lo que seria más cómodo si el texto estuviese centrado y la letra fuese más grande.

Answer (score 0):

Ya encontre una forma.
Me voy a resources\views\layouts y encuentro un archivo llamado app.blade.php
En el se pone información acerca de las "fuentes" con las que damos estilo a nuestra web.
Incluyo este código:

```
<body>
    @include('navegacion')
    <div id="app">
        <main class="py-4">
            @if(session('message')) <!-- Al poner este condicional, se habilita la opción de que al redirigir a una pagina se muestre un mensaje -->
                <div class="alert alert-{{ session('message')[0] }}">
                    <b><center>{{ session('message')[1] }}</center></b>
                </div>
            @endif

            @yield('content')
        </main>
    </div>
</body>
```

Este es el código que procesa los mensajes al redirigir a otra pagina. Fijaros que he añadido , que pone el texto en negrita y , que deja el texto centrado. Al incluirlo cada vez que incluya un texto al redirigir se mostrada centrado y en negrita.